# sensorManager becomes disabled when app is off even though I don't unregister it

Tags: android, kotlin

I use `kotlin`.

I listen sensorManager and it works well `onCreate`.

I need to detect step even when app is off.

So I delete `unregister` line from `onDestroy` cycle.

```
 sensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
```

However on my phone device emulator, if I turn off this app, step count is not detected.

what is the problem? and How can I make this work when app is off?

```
class MyDiaryFragment : Fragment(), SensorEventListener {

    private var _binding: FragmentMyDiaryBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val db = Firebase.firestore
    private val userDB = Firebase.firestore.collection("users")
    private val diaryDB = Firebase.firestore.collection("diary")
    private val userId = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.uid

    private lateinit var sensorManager: SensorManager
    private lateinit var step_sensor: Sensor

    lateinit var broadcastReceiver: BroadCastReceiver

    private var currentMonth: String = ""

    companion object {
        var todayTotalStepCount: Int? = 0
    }


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentMyDiaryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root

        // 걸음수 권한
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION,
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
        ) {
            //ask for permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                requireActivity(),
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION),
                100
            )
        }

        // 걸음수 셋업
        broadcastReceiver = BroadCastReceiver()
        val filter = IntentFilter()
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)
        context?.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter)

        sensorManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        step_sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR)

        if (step_sensor != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, step_sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI)
        } else {
        }

    override fun onSensorChanged(stepEvent: SensorEvent?) {
        Log.d("결과아", "sensorEvent ${stepEvent!!.values[0].toInt()}")

        var currentDate = LocalDate.now()

        todayTotalStepCount = todayTotalStepCount?.plus(stepEvent!!.values[0].toInt())
        binding.todayStepCount.text = todayTotalStepCount.toString()

        // user 내 todayStepCount
        var todayStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
            "todayStepCount" to todayTotalStepCount
        )

        userDB.document("$userId").set(todayStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

        var userStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
            "$currentDate" to todayTotalStepCount
        )

        var periodStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
            "$userId" to todayTotalStepCount
        )

        // user_step_count
        db.collection("user_step_count")
            .document("$userId")
            .set(userStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

        // period_step_count
        db.collection("period_step_count")
            .document("$currentDate")
            .set(periodStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(p0: Sensor?, p1: Int) {
        Log.d("걸음수", "아직")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Activity`s and `Fragment`s are GUI parts. if you want your step counter to work even when app "is off", in the meaning: isn't on foreground, not visible, then you have to use some background `Service`, preferably [`ForegroundService`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services). Keep your sensor logic in there and prepare some communication between GUI-side (e.g. `Fragment`) and background-side like [binding](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) or some [data bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) - when app is on screen then it talk with background service and presents data. When GUI isn't needed and app is "homed" or just device locked then GUI don't need to work and ask for current status, but background logic still works and is storing data for future presentation when user get back to app (GUI)

Comment: this sensorManager is working well on background. But only when app is inactive, it stops.  Even in this case till Foregroundservice is solution?

Comment: when `Activity` goes to background then it is still alive - check out [lifecycle DOC](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). so its "stopped", but not "destroyed". then your `SensorManager` will still be working. But at some point you/user will start using other apps or some background process/service start (sync, download update etc.) and system will be forced to grant some resources to them - memory and CPU

Comment: Then at first it must release some resources from not-used-anymore apps - your backgrounded `Activity`/app will be first on list to destroy. It is `Activity`, so GUI, but it isn't presented on screen, thus keeping it in memory is in fact waste. For registering you may use `applicationContext` got from `context`, but that will give you only "longer live" in backgroud, it's still not preventing GUI-related objects to be cleaned up. Keeping your logic in `ForegroundService` will make it work as long as needed and system won't kill your service for "any reason at any time"